# python string error

Tags: python, string, filepath

```
dir = "C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"

print dir
```

using the code above, i get this... i know that \t is tab

```
C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media  (espacamento)  este\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf
```

but, to fix this i do:

```
dir1 = dir.replace("\\", "\\\\")

print "dir:",dir1
```

and i get

```
C:\\Users\\Geraldes\\Desktop\\media (espacamento)  este\\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf
```

how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 5):

escape your original string's backslashes, or use raw strings.

That is,

```
dir = "C:\\Users\\Geraldes\\Desktop\\media\\teste\\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"
```

or

```
dir = r"C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"
```

**BUT:** be careful with the second choice, because raw strings were not invented for windows paths - they were put there for regular expressions.  Thus, one day you will find that you want to put a backslash at the end of the string, like this:

```
dir = "C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\"
```

It won't work.  This is discussed in greater depth [here](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/).

Comment: thanks guys, i was having a bad time with kinda simple thing ;)

Comment: You can write it as: `r"C:\whatever\whatever\\"`. You'll get two backslashes at the end, but *that doesn't matter.* The path still works fine that way!

Comment: Some things will choke on trailing slashes and double slashes. Not everything parses paths correctly.

Comment: True. I should say that Windows is fine with having an empty segment in a pathname, but who knows what expectations other code might have.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody said but, in addition to expanded backlashes and raw strings, you can also use forward slashes

```
>>> dir = "C:/Users/Geraldes/Desktop/media/teste/ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"
>>> dir
'C:/Users/Geraldes/Desktop/media/teste/ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf'
>>>
```

In fact, forward slashes are accepted by Windows ([Check this](http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/23123-when-did-windows-start-accepting-forward-slash-path-separator) for more info)

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Reservados todos los derechos.

C:\>cd Users/joaquin

C:\Users\joaquin>
```

In any case the safest method is to use `os.path.join` to build your paths in an OS agnostic way.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('C:\Users', 'Geraldes', 'Desktop', 'media', 'teste', 'ASMS.mxf')
'C:\\Users\\Geraldes\\Desktop\\media\\teste\\ASMS.mxf'
>>>
```

Comment: Forward slashes work with most things, but not by a long shot with all. It's not safe to assume that any given thing will work with forward slashes - far too many don't.

Comment: @Chris Morgan, right, there is a discussion on the link I gave. Still I never found any problem for the case discussed (for pathname strings in windows). It would be interesting if you could give an example showing the potential problems of slashes.

Comment: I would also point out that you can use `os.path.normpath` (discussed in the article I linked to in my answer) to avoid any *potential* trouble with slashes in paths

Comment: @joaquin: I have come across some things that don't work properly with forward slashes, but I can't think of any of them offhand. The main nuisance that I've found with it is that path completion in Command Prompt doesn't work if you use forward slashes.

Answer (score 3):

Define a "raw" string:

```
dir = r"C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"
```

Comment: great, never knew about this way of doing it; goodbye double-slashes !

Answer (score 3):

You can use raw formatting:

```
dir = r"C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf"
```

This will print as:

```
>>> print(dir)
C:\Users\Geraldes\Desktop\media\teste\ASMS_TapeA01A1691329.mxf
```

Answer (score 0):

A less obvious and less efficient way is to do the following:

```
import os
os.chdir()#change to each directory separately
print os.getcwd()
```